# Said (as in aforementioned)

Tags: grammaticality, legalese

I was looking at a legal text which went something like this "if you do not wish to receive said advertising check the box below...".

Is it correct to omit the definite article (the) before "said"? It doesn't sound right to my ears but I have seen this before in other texts apart from legal and its use seems extense.

Comment: Yes, it is legalistic, formal writing, and _the_ is omitted as built into _said_.. "To receive... _said_ advertising" means "...to receive 'the identified or quoted' advertising ..."

Comment: The only place where I often see *the said* is in patents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best to refer to Bryan Garner on this.

Looks like “the said” is ok in British English but not in US English:

> *The said*. As used in legal writing, the word *said* is a Middle-English sibling of *aforesaid*, having the sense
>   "above-stated." Originally legal writers would write *the said
>   defendant*-and still do in BrE-just as they would write *the aforesaid
>   defendant* or the *above-stated defendant*. In AmE, however, *the* was
>   dropped before *said*, which has come to act almost as an article.
>   Hence *the said* seems redundant to American ears, though it was well
>   established at one time.

Garner, *A Dictionary of Modern Legal Usage*, 2nd ed., p.778

Comment: Thanks for these excellent insights. But what about its use in texts other than legal? Would you drop the article?

Comment: @Anthony sure. Either way works.